# NiFi's PutHiveStreaming processor does not pick up the properties from the hive-site.xml

Tags: properties, hive, apache-nifi

I would like to insert data into a hive table using NiFi.

The best and easiest option I have seen is to use "PutHiveStreaming" processor. I'm aware of the settings that needs to be met in order to use this processor; some of which are about the hive table that can be done during table creation and some are about hive properties such as:

1. hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
2. hive.compactor.initiator.on = true
3. hive.compactor.worker.threads > 0

I have set these properties in the hive-site.xml in our $HADOOP_HOME/conf directory and provided the full path to this processor under "Hive Configuration Resources". However, these properties in hive-site.xml does not get picked up by this processor.

[Configuration of PutHiveStreaming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1zp5.png)

Unfortunately we do not have permission to $HIVE_HOME/conf or /etc/hive/conf to change hive-site.xml directly.

Could someone explain why the hive-site.xml properties given to this processor does not get picked up and what could be the work around in overriding hive properties when using NiFi? ie: is there a way to execute multiple queries for a given flowfile?

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are server properties that need to be set on the HiveServer2 instance, not the NiFi client.

Also just FYI, if you are running a NiFi version prior to 1.2.0, you may run into [NIFI-3530](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3530). I don't believe this is the issue here, rather that you need to set those properties in the hive-site.xml file used by the HiveServer2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response @mattyb. My question is, what happens if we do not have permission to change the server properties? Is there any way that we could provide our own hive-site.xml?

Comment: Unfortunately no, HiveServer2 has to be configured for ACID tables for PutHiveStreaming to work. You could still use PutHDFS to put your files in Hadoop and create a non-ACID table on top of them.